# FeaturePlot from Seurat: change its title

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

`FeaturePlot` is a function in [Seurat](http://satijalab.org/seurat/pbmc3k_tutorial.html) package.

And in the vignette it is written that if we specify parameter `do.return = TRUE` it should return ggplot2 object. It is not working. My goal here is just to change the title of the plot. In case of violin plot I can do the following:

```
VlnPlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, do.return = TRUE) + labs(title = endothelial_symbols[1])
```

But with `FeaturePlot` similar code fails to work:

```
FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey", "blue"),
                          reduction.use = "tsne", do.return = TRUE) + labs(title = endothelial_symbols[1])
```

Giving the error:

> Error in FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey",  : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with some data that I have and this is working for me:

```
p <- FeaturePlot(object = seurat_object, features.plot = id, cols.use = c("grey", "blue"),
                      reduction.use = "tsne", do.return = TRUE)


lapply(p, function(x){x + labs(title = endothelial_symbols[1])})
```

I think it is because FeaturePlot returns several ggplot objects according to the ids you put. This is returned as a list of plots so you have to iterate each one for labeling.

Comment: This can be “simplified” to ``lapply(p, `+`, labs(title = endothelial_symbols[1]))``.